# Symfony4 - Unable to find template

Tags: templates, twig, symfony4

I'm a beginner in symfony 4, I create a symfony 4 project But I get this error after  adding boostrap themes

```
Unable to find template "blog/home.html.twig" (looked into: 
D:\Interactions\Symfony4\demo\vendor\symfony\twig- 
bridge/Resources/views/Form).
```

This is my action code in the controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 */

public function home()
{
    return $this->render('blog/home.html.twig');
}
```

[image]

Any suggestions to fix that ?

This the content of My twig.yaml:

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templat:es'
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
```

Comment: have you in project root folder "templates/blog/home.html.twig" ?

Comment: yes I have. look to my post I edit it

Comment: Are you using twig? If so please post contents of twig.yaml

Comment: Okey I post it in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fixing

```
default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templat:es'
```

with

```
default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
```

and finally clear the cache